# Testcases randomly fail in container

Tags: selenium, testing, containers, devops

I am running 4 testcases using selenium-java in parallel at a time inside a container and they fail randomly
My container has 4 CPUs and 12GB RAM

What could be the possible reason of failure?

Selenium version 3.14.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please be more specific and include relevant errors.

Comment: The errors which I have encountered are unable to find elements on the page. To be specific the tests fail randomly. It is possible that a Test may pass some time or may even fail